# Is Session created Automatically after the first request?

Tags: java, session, web, networking

I'm newbie in web dev and I have some confusion about **Sessions**.

I know that :

> A session is the total period of time devoted to an activity. In
>   computer systems, a user session begins when a user logs in to or
>   accesses a particular computer, network, or software service. It ends
>   when the user logs out of the service, or shuts down the computer.

From this definition, **I conclude that as soon as the user enters, a session is created Automatically.**

BUT in many web programming language API, there are some method for creating a session **after the first request!**. such as Java:

```
request.getSession(true);
```

[Oracle Docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession())

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or **if the
>   request does not have a session**, creates one.

How is it possible that the client has been connected to the server and has sent a request for server but there is no session?

Comment: *From this definition, I conclude that as soon as the user enters, a session is created Automatically.* why? Where does it say that?

Comment: You don't need a session to send a request to server. For example when you enter google.com, you send a request to google to see main page even if you are not logged in to google.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca because of this definition: *In computer systems, a user session begins when a user logs in to or accesses a particular computer, network, or software service*. I think I'm looking to the session term from networking(osi model) prespective.

Comment: oh. I thought that is necessary for each connection and I thought that it will be created as soon as client sends the first request. I dont know that. thanks for explaining. @GökhanPolat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I conclude that as soon as the user enters, a session is created
> Automatically.

Actually no, a session is not created unless you tell the servlet container explicitly by calling `request.getSession();`

Following are examples to demonstrate this :

1. without calling `request.getSession()` :

- A request made for the first time to /ServletSession; Notice that the session equals **null** :
  [image]
- No **JSESSIONID** cookie is set in the Response Headers; Which means no session was created :
  [image]

2. When calling `request.getSession()` :

- A request made for the first time to /ServletSession; Notice that the session was created :
  [image]
- A **JSESSIONID** cookie is set in the Response Headers :
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

> BUT in many web programming language API, there are some method for
>   creating a session after the first request!. such as Java:

This is because http is stateless unlike other protocols SSH/ftp. In order to identify the user, Server has to create a session for user.

> How is it possible that the client has been connected to the server
>   and has sent a request for server but there is no session?

In context of HTTP: Session is not required for connection. Connection only requires server's address (and probably digital certificate for https). Session is only meant for identification of users. For blogs or news-board where identification of user is not required, Server may choose not to create session for the user.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I thought that it is necessary for each connection to have session. I thought each connection means one session. I think I was looking to the session from wrong perspective ( session in osi model).