# How to get session when okta authenticates the application

Tags: java, session, primefaces, servlet-filters, okta

I did follow the below and got my application working.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcode/main/#grant-type-flow

But I couldnt get the session once the user is authenticated.
I am using ServletFilter to navigate to okta login page(via /authorize endpoint), but i am not getting session in doFilter method.

I am using Primefaces for my UI.

Here is my sample code.
In ServletFilter class... it comes here, but return session always empty.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false); // return null here
```

This is the code in doFilter where I navigate to okta login page.

```
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://XXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=0oa1w21hrnFPT01d7&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20groups&state=xyz&redirect_uri=http://<host>:<port>/app");
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated question with sample code

Comment: why use use `httpServletRequest.getSession(true); `

Comment: getSession(true) creates new session right as session is null. Shouldnt there be a session from okta when authenticated by okta? I want to kill the session from okta and in app as well during signout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521346/is-session-created-automatically-after-the-first-request

Comment: hmm.. let me create the session and see how it goes.. will update the outcome here. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Scary Wombat mentioned in the comment, it works with the new session that created. Thank you.